# Where is this top margin coming from on my Wordpress website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I am using the Twenty Twelve theme that I have customized. I need to remove the top margin above the header menu. See here http://blog.littlenomads.com/

In my child style sheet I have added:

```
    .site-header {
    padding: 0px 0 !important;
    margin: 0px 0 !important;
}
/* remove site margin */
body .site{margin:0 !important;max-width: 100% !important;}

.site-content {
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

I found that solution here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85414/twenty-twelve-theme-remove-margins

I also fully commented out, in the theme Twenty Twelve stylesheet:

```
    /* Minimum width of 960 pixels. */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    body {
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
    }
    /*Brian Ogden 8-12-2014*/
    /*body .site {
        padding: 0 40px;
        padding: 0 2.857142857rem;
        margin-top: 48px;
        margin-top: 3.428571429rem;
        margin-bottom: 48px;
        margin-bottom: 3.428571429rem;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    }*/
    body.custom-background-empty {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    body.custom-background-empty .site,
    body.custom-background-white .site {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}



  * Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .author-avatar {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-top: 0.571428571rem;
    }
    .author-description {
        float: right;
        width: 80%;
    }

    /*.site {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 960px;
        max-width: 68.571428571rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }*/
```

I have also tried the solution found here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-page-title-and-white-space-from-twenty-twelve-theme

Comment: That is it, why would it display a margin and not the wp-admin header bar at the top?

Comment: You might have it set in your `functions.php` to have it hidden, or maybe a option on the theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're logged into your site and it's the wp-admin bar shifting the html/body (html { margin-top: 32px !important; } etc .. ) down with the !important styles that get fed into the head when you're logged in?

Comment: You are correct, do you know how to turn this off when logged in?